# error: Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

Well, I'm trying to compile a java plugin for Bukkit/Spigot, but I'm getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project Websend: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/bruno/spigot/Websend/src/main/java/com/github/websend/WebsendPlayerCommandSender.java:[24,7] error: WebsendPlayerCommandSender is not abstract and does not override abstract method sendTitle(String,String,int,int,int) in Player
```

The respective parts of the file where's the error (I mean):

```
public class WebsendPlayerCommandSender implements Player {
/* This class allows tapping into command output from plugins
 * if the output is sent through the commandsender.
 * Note to anyone having compilation problems: Compile against Bukkit, not CraftBukkit.
 *
 * Tap this method(1.6.4): sendRawMessage, sendMessage(String), sendMessage(String[])
 */

    private final Player baseObject;
    private final Plugin commandTargetPlugin;

    public WebsendPlayerCommandSender(Player baseObject, Plugin commandTargetPlugin) {
        this.baseObject = baseObject;
        this.commandTargetPlugin = commandTargetPlugin;
}

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(java.lang.String param0) {
        PluginOutputManager.handleLogRecord(commandTargetPlugin, new LogRecord(Level.INFO, param0));
        baseObject.sendMessage(param0);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(java.lang.String[] param0) {
        for (String str : param0) {
            PluginOutputManager.handleLogRecord(commandTargetPlugin, new LogRecord(Level.INFO, str));
        }
        baseObject.sendMessage(param0);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendRawMessage(java.lang.String param0) {
        PluginOutputManager.handleLogRecord(commandTargetPlugin, new LogRecord(Level.INFO, param0));
        baseObject.sendRawMessage(param0);
    }
```

And this:

```
public void sendTitle(String string, String string1) {
    baseObject.sendTitle(string, string1);
}
```

The plugin ins't mine, but I need to compile with the correct version of spigot. The problem is that I don't know much about java to solve this error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't think you should be implementing Player...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*If you want to understand the concept then read the whole answer else go to the end and read the block quote for the solution.*

An interface in java as its name suggests is just an interface. If we go specifically in java's perspective. Interface are classes with functions declared but not implemented.
So when some other class implements that interface that class has to implement all the functions of interface also along with its own functions.

For example

This is an interface in java

```
public interface Animal {
   public void eat();
   public void travel();
}
```

This is a class implementing it

```
public class MammalInt implements Animal {
   @Override
   public void eat() {
      System.out.println("Mammal eats");
   }

   @Override
   public void travel() {
      System.out.println("Mammal travels");
   } 

   public int noOfLegs() {
      return 0;
   }
}
```

The only rule you should remember when a class implement an interface it has to implement all of the declared functions in interface.

> In your code you have already implemented `sendMessage` and `sendRawMessage`. Now to remove the error you only have to implement 'sendTitle' as shown in the error.

Comment: I think that I understood this a second before see your message. Following the tips from Malphrush I could see that I would have to implement a lot of things, exactly as you told me. :) Thank you, I think will work soon.

Answer (score 2):

Player is an interface, which contains defined, but unimplemented methods. When

```
WebsendPlayerCommandSender implements Player
```

It's basically signing a contract saying that it will implement these methods that Player did not. It seems WebsendPlayerCommandSender has already overidden the sendMessage and sendRawMessage methods within Player. However, there is a method within Player called send Title that looks like this

```
sendTitle(String string, String string1, int num1, int num2, int num3)
```

And WebsendPlayerCommandSender has not overridden this method. So you'll have to create something like this:

```
@Override
public void sendTitle(String string, String string1, int num1, int num2, int num3){
     //Define behavior here
 }
```

Comment: Following your tips, the error changed to this:

    `error: WebsendPlayerCommandSender is not abstract and does not override abstract method sendTitle(String,String) in Player`

Comment: It's the same thing as before. You'll need to override the sendTitle(String string1, String string2) method. Try placing @Override over the method if it's in the WebsendPlayerCommandSender class but you're still getting the error.

Comment: Correcting, creating a new method with @Override, instead modify the existent, and keeping this, look like worked very well. Now I have other errors from other methods to solve.

Comment: Glad this problems been fixed. If your problem's been solved, please up vote one of the answers. It's considered polite on this site, plus it will help users who have the same problem as you when they view this question :)