# Java Interface Method not being overridden

Tags: java, methods, interface, overriding, abstract

Not sure why my method in the interface is not being overridden.

I get an error message that the class calling the method is not abstract and does not override the method.

Here is the code:

```java
public class Prioritization extends Task {

    public void main(String[] args) {

        setPriority();

        }
    }
}
```

```java
 interface Priority  {

    public void setPriority();
    public void getPriority();

    final int low = 1;
    final int medium = 50;
    final int high = 100;
}
```

```java
public class Task implements Priority {

    private int takeOutgarbage;
    private int drinkBeer;
    private int doHomework;
    private String message;

    public void setPriority(){
        takeOutgarbage = 1;
        drinkBeer = 100;
        doHomework = 50;
    }
}
```

This produces the following error:

Task is not abstract and does not override abstract method getPriority() in Priority
public class Task implements Priority {

Comment: You need to provide definition to the getPriority method as well, like you did with setPriority, inside your 'Task' class. Its blueprint is still incomplete without its definition,hence it is still an abstract(clearly depicted by the error you are getting)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method in superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50796804/class-is-not-abstract-and-does-not-override-abstract-method-in-superclass?force_isolation=true)

Comment: Not to your question, but `public static void main(String[] args) {` - you can't make `main` an instance method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706656/error-class-is-not-abstract-and-does-not-override-abstract-method?force_isolation=true)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452097/class-is-not-abstract-and-does-not-override-abstract-method)

Answer (score 0):

You implement `setPriority`, but not `getPriority`.  You must implement both.

Comment: oh God, sorry everyone, I though the error was setPriority! Sorry for wasting your time!